# converting a string to a tree structure in python

Tags: python

I have a string in python of the following form:

```
line a
line b
  line ba
  line bb
    line bba
  line bc
line c
  line ca
    line caa
line d
```

You can get the idea.  It actually takes a very similar form to python code itself, in that there is a line, and below that line, indentations indicate part of a block, headed by the most recent line of a lesser indentation.

What I need to do is parse this code into a tree sructure, such that each root level line is the key of a dictionary, and its value is a dictionary representing all sublines.  so the above would be:

```
{
'line a' => {},
'line b' => {
  'line ba' => {},
  'line bb' => {
    'line bba' => {}
    },
  'line bc' => {}
  },
'line c' => {
  'line ca' => {
    'line caa' => {}
    },
  },
'line d' => {}
}
```

here's what I've got:

```
def parse_message_to_tree(message):
    buf = StringIO(message)
    return parse_message_to_tree_helper(buf, 0)

def parse_message_to_tree_helper(buf, prev):
    ret = {}
    for line in buf:
        line = line.rstrip()
        index = len(line) - len(line.lstrip())
        print (line + " => " + str(index))
        if index > prev:
            ret[line.strip()] = parse_message_to_tree_helper(buf, index)
        else:
            ret[line.strip()] = {}

    return ret
```

The print shows lines that are left stripped and indexes of 0. I didn't think `lstrip()` was a mutator, but either way the index should still be accurate.

Any suggestions are helpful.

EDIT: Not sure what was going wrong before, but I tried again and it is closer to working, but still not quite right.  Here's what I have now:

```
{'line a': {},
 'line b': {},
 'line ba': {'line bb': {},
             'line bba': {'line bc': {},
                          'line c': {},
                          'line ca': {},
                          'line caa': {},
                          'line d': {}}}}
```

Comment: Have you seen the autovivificating tree hack yet? Might save you some keystrokes: `tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree); t = tree(); t['a']['b']['c'] = "bla"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like already noted before `str.lstrip()` is not a mutator, The index is coming accurate in my system as well.

But the issue is that by the time you realize that the index for the line has increased, `line` is actually point to the increased index line , example , in first case, we note that index for line increases at `line ba` , so `line` points to `line ba` , and then in your `if` condition , you do -

```
ret[line.strip()] = parse_message_to_tree_helper(buf, index)
```

This is wrong, because you would be setting whatever is returned by `parse_message_to_tree_helper()` to `line ba` , not its actual parent.

Also, once you recurse inside the function, you do not come out unless the file has completely been read, but the level in which a certain line is stored in dictionary depends on it coming out of recursion when the indentation has decreased.

I am not sure, if there are any inbuilt libraries that will help you do this , but a code that I was able to come up with (based a lot on your code) -

```
def parse_message_to_tree(message):
    buf = StringIO(message)
    return parse_message_to_tree_helper(buf, 0, None)[0]

def parse_message_to_tree_helper(buf, prev, prevline):
    ret = {}
    index = -1
    for line in buf:
        line = line.rstrip()
        index = len(line) - len(line.lstrip())
        print (line + " => " + str(index))
        if index > prev:
            ret[prevline.strip()],prevline,index = parse_message_to_tree_helper(buf, index, line)
            if index < prev:
                return ret,prevline,index
            continue
        elif not prevline:
            ret[line.strip()] = {}
        else:
            ret[prevline.strip()] = {}
        if index < prev:
            return ret,line,index
        prevline = line
    if index == -1:
        ret[prevline.strip()] = {}
        return ret,None,index
    if prev == index:
        ret[prevline.strip()] = {}
    return ret,None,0
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> print(s)
line a
line b
  line ba
  line bb
    line bba
  line bc
line c
  line ca
    line caa
>>> def parse_message_to_tree(message):
...     buf = StringIO(message)
...     return parse_message_to_tree_helper(buf, 0, None)[0]
...
>>> def parse_message_to_tree_helper(buf, prev, prevline):
...     ret = {}
...     index = -1
...     for line in buf:
...         line = line.rstrip()
...         index = len(line) - len(line.lstrip())
...         print (line + " => " + str(index))
...         if index > prev:
...             ret[prevline.strip()],prevline,index = parse_message_to_tree_helper(buf, index, line)
...             if index < prev:
...                 return ret,prevline,index
...             continue
...         elif not prevline:
...             ret[line.strip()] = {}
...         else:
...             ret[prevline.strip()] = {}
...         if index < prev:
...             return ret,line,index
...         prevline = line
...     if index == -1:
...         ret[prevline.strip()] = {}
...         return ret,None,index
...     if prev == index:
...         ret[prevline.strip()] = {}
...     return ret,None,0
...
>>> pprint.pprint(parse_message_to_tree(s))
line a => 0
line b => 0
  line ba => 2
  line bb => 2
    line bba => 4
  line bc => 2
line c => 0
  line ca => 2
    line caa => 4
{'line a': {},
 'line b': {'line ba': {}, 'line bb': {'line bba': {}}, 'line bc': {}},
 'line c': {'line ca': {'line caa': {}}}}
>>> s = """line a
... line b
...   line ba
...   line bb
...     line bba
...   line bc
... line c
...   line ca
...     line caa
... line d"""
>>> pprint.pprint(parse_message_to_tree(s))
line a => 0
line b => 0
  line ba => 2
  line bb => 2
    line bba => 4
  line bc => 2
line c => 0
  line ca => 2
    line caa => 4
line d => 0
{'line a': {},
 'line b': {'line ba': {}, 'line bb': {'line bba': {}}, 'line bc': {}},
 'line c': {'line ca': {'line caa': {}}},
 'line d': {}}
```

You would need to test the code for any more bugs or some missed cases.

Comment: thanks.  I'd figured out that I needed to include the previous line in the parameters, but I hadn't gotten to the pop out issue yet.

Answer (score 1):

`lstrip()` isn't a mutator, see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip):

> string.lstrip(s[, chars])
>
> Return a copy of the string with leading characters removed. If chars is omitted or None, whitespace characters are removed. If given
>   and not None, chars must be a string; the characters in the string
>   will be stripped from the beginning of the string this method is
>   called on.

And your code seems to work with that sample text on my machine.

Comment: odd. It wasnt working before but it does seem to be closer to working now. The issue I'm having now is that it doesn't "pop back up" on `line c` and `line d`. so `line c` is in `line bba`'s map

Comment: actually its more poorly structured than that: `{'line a': {}, 'line b': {}, 'line ba': {'line bb': {}, 'line bba': {'line bc': {}, 'line ca': {}, 'line c': {}, 'line d': {}, 'line caa': {}}}}`

Answer (score 1):

Another answer, using stack instead of recursion.  It took a few iterations to get to this version, and it seems to handle several possible input scenarios, but can't guarantee total absence of bugs!  It's a tricky problem indeed.  Hopefully my comments illustrate a correct line of thought.  Thanks for sharing the problem.

```
text = '''line a
line b
  line ba
  line bb
    line bba
  line bc
line c
  line ca
    line caa
line d'''

root_tree = {}
stack = []
prev_indent, prev_tree = -1, root_tree

for line in text.splitlines():

    # compute current line's indent and strip the line
    origlen = len(line)
    line = line.lstrip()
    indent = origlen - len(line)
    print indent, line

    # no matter what, every line has its own tree, so let's create it.
    tree = {}  

    # where to attach this new tree is dependent on indent, prev_indent
    # assume: stack[-1] was the right attach point for the previous line
    # then: let's adjust the stack to make that true for the current line

    if indent < prev_indent:
        while stack[-1][0] >= indent:
            stack.pop()
    elif indent > prev_indent:
        stack.append((prev_indent, prev_tree))

    # at this point: stack[-1] is the right attach point for the current line
    parent_indent, parent_tree = stack[-1]
    assert parent_indent < indent

    # attach the current tree
    parent_tree[line] = tree

    # update state
    prev_indent, prev_tree = indent, tree

print len(stack)
print stack
print root_tree
```