# converting a python string to tree structure: continued

Tags: python

[Here is where the question started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32101253/converting-a-string-to-a-tree-structure-in-python)

Using the top answer to that question, I was able to get something working.  But there is now a small modification.  The data I am getting is formatted as follows:

```
key (metadata) = value
```

If there is a line that has a child, value will be blank and will refer to the lines below, like so:

```
    key-0 (meta) = 0
    key-1 (meta) =
        key-11 (meta) = 1
        key-12 (meta) = 
            key-121 (meta = 2
        key-13 (meta) = 3
    key-2 (meta) = 4
    key-3 (meta) = 
        key-31 (meta) = 5
```

etc.  The key will never have spaces.  What I need is the following tree structure:

```
  {
    'key-0': ['0'],
    'key-1': {
      'key-11': ['1'], 
      'key-12': {
        'key-121': ['2']
      }, 
      'key-13': ['3']
    },
    'key-2': ['4'],
    'key-3': {
      'key-31': ['5']
    }
  }
```

Here's what I have

```
def parse_message_to_tree(message):
    firstline = message.split('\n', 1)[0]
    prefix = len(firstline) - len(firstline.lstrip())
    buf = StringIO(message)
    return parse_message_to_tree_helper(buf, prefix, None)[0]

def parse_message_to_tree_helper(buf, prev, prevline):
    ret = {}
    index = -1
    for line in buf:
        line = line.rstrip()
        index = len(line) - len(line.lstrip())
        if index > prev:
            key = prevline.split()[0]
            val = prevline.split('=')[-1]
            ret[key],prevline,index = parse_message_to_tree_helper(buf, index, line)
            if index < prev:
                return ret,prevline,index
            continue
        elif not prevline:
            key = line.split()[0]
            value = line.split('=')[-1]
            if key not in ret:
                ret[key] = []
            ret[key].append(value.strip())            
        else:
            key = prevline.split()[0]
            value = prevline.split('=')[-1]
            if key not in ret:
                ret[key] = []
            ret[key].append(value.strip())
        if index < prev:
            return ret,line,index
        prevline = line
    if index == -1 and prevline:
        key = prevline.split()[0]
        value = prevline.split('=')[-1]
        if key not in ret:
            ret[key] = []
        ret[key].append(value.strip())
        return ret,index, None
    if prev == index and prevline:
        key = prevline.split()[0]
        value = prevline.split('=')[-1]
        if key not in ret:
            ret[key] = []
        ret[key].append(value.strip())
    return ret,0,None
```

This usually works, with one problem.  when the first line does not have any children (as in the example), it's value is repeated in the dict:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(parse_message_to_tree(test))
{'key-0': ['0', '0'],
 'key-1': {'key-11': ['1'], 'key-12': {'key-121': ['2']}, 'key-13': ['3']},
 'key-2': ['4'],
 'key-3': {'key-31': ['5']}}
```

And I can't figure out why.

**EDIT**: This problem can be solved by adding a check before I append:

```
if value.strip() not in ret[key]:
  ret[key].append(value.strip())
```

But I'd still like to figure out WHY it's happening. There must be a flaw in the control flow somewhere but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you provide does work, but it doesn't solve the initial problem. It's just a quick fix. What is happening is that you're duplicating on the first line. These two cases:

```
    elif not prevline:
        key = line.split()[0]
        value = line.split('=')[-1]
        if key not in ret:
            ret[key] = []
        ret[key].append(value.strip())            
    else:
        key = prevline.split()[0]
        value = prevline.split('=')[-1]
        if key not in ret:
            ret[key] = []
        ret[key].append(value.strip())
```

do essentially the same thing. You can solve this by changing your `elif` to this:

```
elif not prevline:
    prevline = line
    continue
```

Or you could completely get rid of `elif` and just have the `if` `else` and pass in the `prevline` value in the first method.

```
def parse_message_to_tree(message):
    msg = message.split('\n', 1)
    firstline = msg[0]
    prefix = len(firstline) - len(firstline.lstrip())
    buf = StringIO(msg[1])
    return parse_message_to_tree_helper(buf, prefix, firstline)[0]
```